# How do I create an object on a randomly selected integer?

Tags: java, object

I'm very new to this topic. My prof and classmates are all unresponsive.

Context: Program is a math quiz which creates one of four different quiz questions at random.

```
int rand;

rand = (int)(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
```

Here's where I run into trouble:

```
switch (rand) {
        case 1:
                AdditionProblem q1 = new AdditionProblem();
                break;
        case 2:
                SubtractionProblem q1 = new SubtractionProblem();
                break;
        case 3:
                MultiplicationProblem q1 = new MultiplicationProblem();

                break;
        case 4:
                DivisionProblem q1 = new DivisionProblem();
                break;
```

This says duplicate local variable q1 so I tried if/else:

```
        if (rand == 1) {
            AdditionProblem q1 = new AdditionProblem();
        }
        else if (rand == 2) {
            SubtractionProblem q1 = new SubtractionProblem();
        }
        else if (rand == 3) {
            MultiplicationProblem q1 = new MultiplicationProblem();
        }
        else {
            DivisionProblem q1 = new DivisionProblem();
        }
```

This says q1 cannot be resolved. What am I doing wrong?

### Edit

Made a supertype and it now declares correctly but it says `The local variable q1 may not have been initialized` when trying to call something from it:

```
System.out.println(q1.getProblem());
```

Here's the code for the Problem and AdditionProblem classes:

Problem.java

```
package MathQuiz;

public class Problem {
    
    private int x, y, answer;
    
    public String getProblem() {
        return "Problem text here";
    }
    
    public int getAnswer() {
        return answer;
    }
}
```

AdditionProblem.java

```
package MathQuiz;

public class AdditionProblem extends Problem {
    
    private int x, y, answer;
    
    public AdditionProblem() {
        
        x = (int)(10 + 40*Math.random());
        y = (int)(30 * Math.random());
        answer = x + y;
    }
    
    public String getProblem() {
        return "Compute the sum: " + x + " + " + y;
    }
    
    public int getAnswer() {
        return answer;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend to use a [switch expression](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/language/switch-expressions.html).

Comment: Can you share your code after you fixed the supertype issue?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a single shared variable of a supertype of all four kinds of problems:

```
Problem q1;
switch (rand) {
  case 1:
    q1 = new AdditionProblem();
    break;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, making a shared supertype made it declare correctly, but I ran into further problems. I edited the main post accordingly. I've no idea what I need to do or not do.

Comment: Only declare the variables `x, y, answer` in one place.  You may have to mark them non private or use getters.